# Getting NPE after creating new object of class

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a 'game' using swing and I'm experiencing a problem which I can't solve. It's probably something easy and obvious but I still can't figure out. Here's a piece of my code:

```
public class LevelOne {

private static Crate[] crates = new Crate[3];        
public LevelOne(){
    crates[0].setX(200);
    crates[0].setY(200);
    crates[1].setX(280);
    crates[1].setY(40);
    crates[2].setX(440);
    crates[2].setY(40);

}
//more code here
}
```

I try to create object of `LevelOne` class to make my `crates` variable living. (is this a way to do so?).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LevelOne l = new LevelOne();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("blabla");
    Board board = new Board();
    frame.add(board);
    frame.setSize(805, 830);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setFocusable(false);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    frame.setLocation(400, 200);
    board.requestFocus(true);

}
```

It gives me NPE at line

```
LevelOne l = new LevelOne();
```

As I said, it's a small piece of project but I think this might solve whole issue. I'm using this `Crate[]` crates to paint components on my board, to check collision and other stuff. Without creating object of `LevelOne` class, I still get NPE when trying to draw them. Any suggestions, ideas, solutions?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to initialize elements in crates:

```
private static Crate[] crates = new Crate[3];        

public LevelOne(){
    crates[0] = new Crate(); // <= add this
    crates[0].setX(200);
    crates[0].setY(200);
    // same for other elements
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to propagate `Crate` object into your `crates` array. You are getting NullPointerException because `crates` array doesn't have any reference of `Carte` in it. Do the following.

```
private static Crate[] crates = new Crate[3];        
public LevelOne(){
    for(int i = 0; i < crates.length; i++)
        crates[i] = new Crate();
    crates[0].setX(200);
    crates[0].setY(200);
    crates[1].setX(280);
    crates[1].setY(40);
    crates[2].setX(440);
    crates[2].setY(40);

}
```

Comment: This will make all crates the same object, no?

Comment: Don't you think this can be problematic

Comment: @RC As far as the OP's code I don't see any problems... but in case of different constructors can be problematic or can be problematic if he wants to propagate objects to only some of the array index.

Comment: @RC marvelous catch... changed the answer. I wasn't thinking rightly.